# How to optimize size of Android Application..?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a application which contains Google maps with different features like get near  places their detail information and get direction.

For this i have use some .jar files mention below,I refer [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) for doing this.

```
android-support-v4
google-api-client-1.10.3-beta
google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta
google-http-client-1.10.3-beta
google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta
google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta
gson-2.1
guava-11.0.1
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4
jsr305-1.3.9
protobuf-java-2.2.0
```

but problem is due to this .jar files my application's total size is near about 6mb, which is very big.

Please suggest me the way to optimize my application.

Comment: Do you use proguard? That can remove unused classes: http://blog.androidquery.com/2011/06/android-optimization-with-proper.html - also unzip your apk and have a look at what takes up the most space, `classes.dex` is all the sourcecode, the rest are usually resources

Comment: @zapl could we use proguard without release mode???

Comment: I guess so but I have never tried and don't know how.

Comment: @zapl Quoting from doc "ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode".